# javascript - could not make closest element to work with query selector

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JavaScript for a calendar events(elements):

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
      var d = new Date(item.event_date);
      var datestring = d.getFullYear() + "," + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "," + d.getDate();
      events.push({
            'Date': new Date(datestring),
            'Title': item.event_name + `<div><span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
     ${item.event_description}</span></div>`,
            'Link': function()({
                document.querySelector('#myPopup').closest("#myPopup")
                .classList.toggle("show");
              }
            },
          );
```

and the related html is like this:

```
<li class="cld-day currMonth"><p class="cld-number eventday">14<span class="cld-title">    
<a href="#">Children's Day<div><span class="popuptext show" id="myPopup">    
on the occassion of birthday of Pandit Jawaharlal Nehru</span></div></a></span></p></li>

<li class="cld-day currMonth"><p class="cld-number eventday">20<span class="cld-title">
<a href="#">Test Event Nov<div><span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
Testing event in November detail</span></div></a></span></p></li>
```

Now when I click on the first element, the popup shows correctly, but when I click on the second element, the popup shows but for the first element and above first element.

How I can resolve this?

Comment: Note `querySelector('#myPopup').closest("#myPopup")` is just going to select itself as closest() starts the search with the initial element.

Comment: How are you associating the function with the element that you click on? In an event listener, you can use use `event.target` or `this` to get the element that was clicked.

Comment: Your function is missing the parameter list. It should be `function() { document.querySelector... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id must be unique for each link.

Just create a unique id from the date and you're good to go.

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
  var d = new Date(item.event_date);
  var datestring =
    d.getFullYear() + "," + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "," + d.getDate();
  var id = (d.getTime() / 1000) | 0;
  events.push({
    Date: new Date(datestring),
    Title:
      item.event_name +
      `<div><span class="popuptext" id="${id}">
             ${item.event_description}</span></div>`,
    Link: function() {
      document
        .getElementById(id)
        .classList.toggle("show");
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT: use .getElementById instead of .querySelector.

Comment: Perfect. just make a small change to your answer.`document.querySelector(id) is throwing error like - `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '1573689600' is not a valid selector.
    at HTMLAnchorElement.Link` I just replaced that with `document.getElementById(id)`

Comment: Ah yes of course. My bad, I was tired. Should be that or `querySelector(\`#${id}\`)`.